# Почему операции streamApi принимают другой параметр без ошибки компиляции?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Решил для себя подразобраться с method reference и после некоторых тестов пришел к такому примеру:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<String, String> capitalize = StringUtils::capitalize;
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("how", "this", "works?");
    messages.forEach(capitalize); //идея жалуется
    messages.forEach(StringUtils::capitalize); //все в порядке
}
```

У стримов все тоже самое

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 42;
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("how", "this", "works?");
    messages.stream().map(supplier).forEach(System.out::println); //ошибка
    messages.stream().map(s -> supplier.get()).forEach(System.out::println); //все ок
}
```

Нет явного понимания, почему так. Я полагаю, что где-то там внутри используется просто абстрактный метод функционального интерфейса или как-то оборачивается это все ... Хотелось бы исправить этот пробел в знаниях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, в обоих случаях компилятор "ругается" из-за несоответствия типов.

Сначала разберём ваш первый код. Вы пишете *method* *reference* для типа `Function`, и пишете его правильно, но тип входного параметра у метода `forEach` другой - это `Consumer`.

Так выглядит функциональный интерфейс `Function`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
    // and other methods
}
```

Его абстрактный метод принимает на вход значение и возвращает значение.

А вот так выглядит функциональный интерфейс `Consumer`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
    // and other methods
}
```

Его абстрактный метод принимает на вход значение и ничего не возвращает.

Лямбда-выражение для обоих методов может выглядеть совершенно идентично:

```
Function<String, String> capitalize = s -> StringUtils.capitalize(s);
Consumer<String> consumer = s -> StringUtils.capitalize(s);
```

В первом случае мы принимаем строку и возвращаем её, переведённую в верхний регистр, а во втором случае просто принимаем строку, но результат действия с ней не возвращается функцией.

Эти лямбда-выражения можно сократить до method reference, как вы и сделали для `Function`:

```
Function<String, String> capitalize = StringUtils::capitalize;
Consumer<String> consumer = StringUtils::capitalize;
```

Теперь проверим предупреждения компилятора:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<String, String> function = StringUtils::capitalize; // method reference для типа Function
    Consumer<String> consumer = StringUtils::capitalize; // method reference для типа Consumer
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("how", "this", "works?");
    messages.forEach(function); // ошибка, ведь передаём переменную типа Function
    messages.forEach(consumer); // ошибки нет, ведь передаём переменную типа Consumer
    messages.forEach(StringUtils::capitalize); // ошибки нет, так как автоматически предполагается тип Consumer
}
```

Теперь разберём ваш второй код. Вы пишете лямбда-выражение для интерфейса `Supplier`, и пишете его правильно, но тип входного параметра у метода `map` другой - это `Function`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 42; // лямбда-выражение для Supplier
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("how", "this", "works?");
    messages.stream().map(supplier).forEach(System.out::println); // ошибка, так как требуется тип Function
    messages.stream().map(() -> 42).forEach(System.out::println); // ошибка, так как требуется тип Function
}
```

`Supplier` просто выдаёт значение, не принимая никаких параметров. А `Function`, как мы убедились выше, принимает параметр и возвращает значение. Код с корректным лямбда-выражением для типа `Function` и поясняющими комментариями приведён ниже.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 42; // лямбда-выражение для Supplier
    Function<String, Integer> function = s -> supplier.get(); // лямбда-выражение для Function: не просто возвращаем значение, но и принимаем параметр
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("how", "this", "works?");
    messages.stream().map(function).forEach(System.out::println); // работает
    messages.stream().map(s -> supplier.get()).forEach(System.out::println); // работает
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ, но я хотел бы уточнить один момент, а именно StringUtils имеет вот такой метод
`
public static String capitalize(final String str) {
//code
}
`
И видя его я понимаю, что я вижу Function. Но ссылаясь на этот метод в forEach который принимает Consumer не особо понятно, какой механизм это все пропускает, если так можно сказать.
Да, извините, не освоился еще с редактором)

Comment: `Function` использует этот метод как `{return capitalize(s);}`, а `Consumer` - просто как `{capitalize(s);}`

Comment: То есть я так понимаю, что я ему передаю метод, он мне отвечает, мол, да, я могу сделать из него Consumer и соответственно делает, выкидывая результат. 
Попробовал сейчас наоборот, в map передал ссылку на void метод и он у меня ругается, ибо получить результат и выкинуть его это одно, а взять ничего и создать что-то - это другое
Спасибо

Comment: Да, вы всё правильно поняли. Рад, что разобрались)